# Why is the body of the node request is always a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I am trying to use a npm package to do API GET calls in node. However, for some reasons, no matter what, the body of the request is always a string (instead of an object or array). Anyone know why that is the case and what can I do to stop it from doing that?

Example (this API is supposed to return an array, yet the body is a string):
body: '["I call this turf ‘n’ turf. It\'s a 16 oz T-bone and a 24 oz porterhouse. Also, whiskey and a cigar. I am going to consume all of this at the same time because I am a free American."]'

Comment: Generally when you send data to and from a server, it is sent as a 'serialized' string. This string is usually in XML or JSON format. Since it looks like you are working with a JSON string you should be able to parse the sting using `var obj = JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Huh, but it seems like this is a specific issue with using the request package from npm, as if I just go to the network tab in chrome and monitor the incoming package, the API returns an array...

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183228/make-a-get-request-to-json-api-in-node-js). I presume this is something similar to what you are doing (Ajax request using Node). See the answer given shows that the `body` is parsed using the `JSON.parse()` function to retrieve the original object from the string.

Comment: Ah ha I see. I'm still new at node and backend stuffs, so is most data back from a server all translated (serialized) to string? Is that just a convention or is it because of something else?

Comment: I guess you could look at how HTTP works - Hyper Text Transfer Protocol. This is the method used for sending and receiving data over the internet. The data is sent in a readable string format.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! Do you mind putting your answer as an answer here so I can upvote and mark you as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you send data to and from a server, it is sent as a 'serialized' string. This string is usually in XML or JSON format. Since it looks like you are working with a JSON string you should be able to parse the sting using var obj = JSON.parse(str).

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183228/make-a-get-request-to-json-api-in-node-js). I presume this is something similar to what you are doing (Ajax request using Node). See the answer given shows that the body is parsed using the JSON.parse() function to retrieve the original object from the string.

Also take a look at [how HTTP works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) - Hyper Text Transfer Protocol. This is the method used for sending and receiving data over the internet. The data is sent in a readable string format.